# 'Header cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: next.js

'Header cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return return type 'Promise' is not a valid JSX element. Type 'Promise' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key

```
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import LogoutButton from "./LogoutButton";
import { unstable_getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";

async function Header() {
  const session = await unstable_getServerSession();

  if (session)
    return (
      <header className="sticky top-0 z-50 bg-white flex justify-between items-center p-10 shadow-sm">
        <div className="flex space-x-2">
          <Image
            className="rounded-full mx-2 object-contain"
            height={10}
            width={50}
            src={session.user?.image!}
            alt="Profile Picture"
          />
          <div>
            <p className="text-blue-400">Logged in as:</p>
            <p className="font-bold text-lg">{session.user?.name}</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <LogoutButton />
      </header>
    );

  return (
    <header className="sticky top-0 z-50 bg-white flex justify-center items-center p-10 shadow-sm">
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center space-y-5">
        <div className="flex space-x-2 items-center">
          <Image
            src="https://links.papareact.com/jne"
            height={10}
            width={50}
            alt="Logo"
          />
          <p className="text-blue-400">Welcome to Meta Messenger</p>
        </div>
        <Link
          href="/auth/signin"
          className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
        >
          Sign In
        </Link>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

I tried using an async function

Comment: what version of react and nextjs are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Types for async function components have not quite landed yet. You could subscribe to [this PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/65135). Once it lands upgrading `@types/react` and `typescript` should do the trick.

Until then, you could either do a typecast, e.g.

```tsx
export default Header as unknown as () => JSX.Element;
```

OR

do this dance on every usage site:

```tsx
{/* @ts-expect-error Server Component */}
<Header />
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading react types works for me

```bash
pnpm add -D @types/react@latest @types/react-dom@latest
```